# VBA for Dummies example, display message box giving syntax error

Tags: vba, syntax-error, messagebox

I am trying to run this code from an example in 'VBA for Dummies'

It is giving me 'Syntax Error' at the message box line, not very encouraging

```
Sub AddEmUp()
  Sum = 1 + 1
  MsgBox “The answer is “ & Sum
End Sub
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: The problem are the quotation marks. Try to delete and re-type both and re-run program. It should look like `MsgBox "The answer is " & Sum`.

Comment: Wow can't even copy and paste code right! Worked perfect thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed by L42, it  is the quotation usage; While you might have problems to copy-paste, it could be the source that have wrong formatting as well.

Try to always type your code when learning, it will still more to you :)